# AWS , iOS, cognito, confusion

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on an app that loads files into s3, following this example

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample/Objective-C

In the read me it says

```
In the Amazon Cognito console, use Amazon Cognito to create a new identity 
pool. Obtain the PoolID constant. Make sure the role has full permissions for 
the bucket you created.
```

This is confusing for me, When I go to IAM roles, And to manage users, I see I can add AmazonS3FullAccess Policy, but I cannot specify the actual bucket name !!
When clicking on show policy I get this pop up

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": "*"
   }
 ]
}
```

and its read only . I have an s3 bucket and want to make sure the IAM user can access it but can't figure out how to do that on the AWS website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after digging around, I found the way to create a custom policy and update the s3 bucket in it and attach it to a role. in IAM, under dashboard go to policies -> create policy -> Copy an AWS Managed Policy ( I recommend ) and form there you configure it. Hope this helps others, still think the site needs to be better documented.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-configure AmazonS3FullAccess policy gives full access to Amazon S3, hence there is no restriction on bucket name.

Here is an example of policy that restrict to a specific bucket and "directory" in S3 only if the directory name match the user's Cognito user ID.

You restrict access to a specific Bucket / Directory / File by using the `Resource` section of the policy.

```
{
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::iosdemo-upload/pictures/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
         ]
      }
```

To discover more about Amazon S3 policies, I would suggest you to walk through these steps
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html